# jQuery toggle divs not working right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have divs opening and closing some data. The problem is that when I click the button it opens, changes text to collapse but when I click 2nd time it won's change the text to Find support.
The 2nd issue is if I click on different div, it will close it first if other div were open.
I want it to close all and open the one clicked and change from collapse to Find Support.
Any help here?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".findButton").click(function () {         

            $(".findButton").val('Find Support');            
            $(this).val('Collapse');
            $("id^=ilsList").remove();
            $(this).closest($("#ilsList").appendTo($(this).parent()).slideToggle());          
       });        
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sw0zn36e/)

Comment: you're always changing the button you click to .val('Collapse')

Comment: @indubitablee, I know, I tried everything and I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/sw0zn36e/7/

```
<div class="DivGroup">
    <label>Bay Village Branch - <b>Cuyahoga County Public Library</b></label>
    <input type="button" onclick="LoadBranches('CuyahogaCounty')" value="Find Support" class="findButton"/>
    <div class="IlsTable" style="display:none;">
        <img src="../../Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif" style="display: none;" id="ajaxLoader"/>
        TEXT            TEXT    TEXT    
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".findButton").on('click', function () {
        if($(this).val() == 'Find Support') {
            $(".findButton").val('Find Support');            
            $(this).val('Collapse');
            $('.DivGroup').find('.IlsTable').slideUp();
            $(this).closest('.DivGroup').find('.IlsTable').slideDown();                        
        }
        else {
            $(".findButton").val('Find Support');
            $('.DivGroup').find('.IlsTable').slideUp();
        }                    
    });    
});
```

EDITED to address the issue of toggling divs. I changed the structure of the html a little bit so i could utilize classes more effectively. hope this helps!

Comment: almost! When you have one open and you open the other div, it needs to open the one you clicked. Now it closes it.

Comment: @Grasper, oh, apologies (I thought the only issue was the button text), I will work on this tomorrow unless someone has completed it by that time

Comment: @Grasper see the editted fiddle and code: http://jsfiddle.net/sw0zn36e/7/ hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~2nd EDIT ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

OK, please look at this edited answer:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~2nd EDIT ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Ok, please try this change:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".findButton").click(function () {      
    if ($(this).val() == 'Find Support') {   
        $('.findButton').each(function(){
            $(this).val('Find Support');
        });
        $(this).val('Collapse');            
        $(this).closest($("#ilsList").appendTo($(this).parent()).slideDown());            
    } else {       
        $(this).val('Find Support');
        $('.IlsTable').not(this).each(function(){
             $(this).slideUp();
        });
    }                
});        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sw0zn36e/4

Comment: Click find on one div, then collapse in the same one.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare button previous value with the current one:

```js
$(".findButton").click(function() {

  $(this).val(function() {
    return $(this).val() === 'Collapse' ? 'Find support' : 'Collapse';
  });
  $("id^=ilsList").remove();
  $(this).closest($("#ilsList").appendTo($(this).parent()).slideToggle());
});
```

```css
#ilsList {
  display: none;
}
.IlsTable {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  padding: 20px 60px 20px 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.trResult,
.DivGroup {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc !important;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px 0 10px !important;
  width: 100%;
}
.DivGroup {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.DivGroup label {
  font-size: 17px;
}
button:hover,
.findButton {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  color: #333;
}
button,
.findButton {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  border: 1px solid #999 !important;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #666 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.findButton {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1d6096;
  border: medium none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 8px 21px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="DivGroup">
  <label>Bay Village Branch - <b>Cuyahoga County Public Library</b>

  </label>
  <input type="button" onclick="LoadBranches('CuyahogaCounty')" value="Find Support" class="findButton">
</div>
<div class="DivGroup">
  <label>Bay Village Branch - <b>Cuyahoga County Public Library</b>

  </label>
  <input type="button" onclick="LoadBranches('CuyahogaCounty')" value="Find Support" class="findButton">
</div>
<div class="DivGroup">
  <label>Bay Village Branch - <b>Cuyahoga County Public Library</b>

  </label>
  <input type="button" onclick="LoadBranches('CuyahogaCounty')" value="Find Support" class="findButton">
</div>
<div class="IlsTable" id="ilsList">
  <img src="../../Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif" style="display: none;" id="ajaxLoader">TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
```